# Javascript - print the name of an enum from a value

Tags: javascript, enums

Is there a way I can print the values of the enum field given the int value? for example I have the following enum:

```
refractiveIndex = {"vacuum": 1, "air": 1.000293, "water": 1.33, "diamond": 2.419};
```

If I have a value, is there a way to print the name of the enum.  For example lets say I have a variable set to 1 and I want to print out "vacuum", how do I do that:

```
var value = 1;
console.log(refractiveIndex(value)); // Should print "vacuum" to console
```

?

Comment: So you basically want to switch the keys and the values in your original object?

Comment: What if there are two elements with the same refractive index?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and test against the value of the property.

```js
var refractiveIndex = {"vacuum": 1, "air": 1.000293, "water": 1.33, "diamond": 2.419},
    value = 1,
    key;

Object.keys(refractiveIndex).some(function (k) {
    if (refractiveIndex[k] === value) {
        key = k;
        return true;
    }
});
console.log(key);
```

ES6

```js
var refractiveIndex = {"vacuum": 1, "air": 1.000293, "water": 1.33, "diamond": 2.419},
    value = 1,
    key = Object.keys(refractiveIndex).find(k => refractiveIndex[k] === value);

console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/1qxp3cf8/

use for...of to go through the object properties and check if it equals the value you're looking for.

```
refractiveIndex = {
  "vacuum": 1,
  "air": 1.000293,
  "water": 1.33,
  "diamond": 2.419
};

var value = 1;
for (prop in refractiveIndex) {
  if (refractiveIndex[prop] == value) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
```

if you wanted it as a function you could write it as this:

```
function SearchRefractive(myValue) {
    for (prop in refractiveIndex) {
      if (refractiveIndex[prop] == myValue) {
        return prop;
      }
    }
}
var value = 1;
SearchRefractive(value);
```